# How to create new empty branch through GitHub.com?

Tags: git, github, branch

So I have been trying for quite while asking people on programming help through discord, searching on Google etc etc and nothing was found.

What I am trying to do is to create new branch without having any files from 'master' meaning basically an empty branch and I am stuck not knowing what to do from here and I haven't found a solution through that to do directly on github.com

[image: Branch master]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub don't allow this because that's not a standard need.

But you could do:

`git checkout --orphan my-new-branch`

that create a branch not link to any commit.
And then commit.

You will have a new commit history/tree root (depending on the file you put into it, probably not mergeable with any branch belonging to the other graph without conflicts).

Comment: I have never used bash before and I am not sure how I can "connect" to my respo

Comment: @Thrillofit86 Just open a command line and be sure you are in the repository folder. That's all. (if, like normally it should be, git is in your PATH)

Answer (score 0):

A branch is always a copy from some other but for the initial branch (master).

What you can do is create a branch, then remove all, then commit. However, do not merge the branch on the master or you will loose everything (from that version).

Comment: What about if there is quite alot of files? I mean that would take quite a while for me to delete haha

Comment: Branch from the initial commit on the master branch to get less files, or create a new repository :-)